# Sending TCP data in parallel

Tags: sockets, tcp, zeromq

I have a set up that involves exactly one client and one server.  The client can generate 32K data really fast.  As I generate that data I'd like to send it in parallel over TCP to the server and have it reassembled in the same order that I sent it out in.

So I have the thought where I add each 32K packet to a queue on the client, then something sends out those packets in parallel.  On the server, those packets are received in some random order, but then put back in order into a queue and then I can simple dequeue the packets.  I have a picture of this set up:

[image: Fanout/fanin]

Does this set up have a name?  Fanout/fanin?  What should I be searching for?  It seems middleware such as ZeroMQ *might* help, but I haven't been able to see any specific examples that display this type of architecture.

I assume this is a solved problem with some nice open source libraries out there, but my assumptions have been wrong in the past.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly? It seems like you're just creating a problem and then trying to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: You are attempting to use multiple server<>client connections to try and utilize multiple routes to speed up overall throughput?

Comment: Martin: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: David: I'm trying to send data from the client to the server in an efficient way.  So I generate some data I want to send to the server - I don't want to block while it takes 300ms to send that data over a slow connection.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how much speedup you might get, but the attempt could surely be made.  It would be wise to try and set up some sort of simple trial to see if any speedup is worth it.  Maybe set up two server processes on different ports on one box, and continually send stuff to them from two client processes on the other - no synchro, or real data, just lots of stuff to see if the transport is any faster than one server and one client.

Comment: I guess you already have the data as compressed as it reasonably can be?

Comment: Martin: Yes, data is compressed.  I keep trying to find a good analogy to this problem...I want to copy a file from a client to a server over the Internet.  If I only have one packet in flight at a time the aggregate time will be higher than if I have multiple packets in flight.

Comment: If the pathway between your client and your server is N kilobytes per second, then you won't get more than N kilobytes per second of data transfer across it, regardless of how many TCP streams you split the data up into.  (e.g. you could have 1 300 kbps TCP connection, or two 150 kbps connections, or three 100 kbps connections, but the end result will be the same).  If your problem is really that you don't want to block, that's a separate issue which you can address by using non-blocking I/O, or a separate I/O thread.

Comment: @BigHands79 TCP already do what you want (TCP doesn't really send one packet a time), for most of the time calling send won't be blocking and you can use non-blocking (socket is blocking when send buffer is full not while waiting for ack). IMO there is no need for your optimization. You can use zeromq, it will work. take a look at https://github.com/zeromq/filemq

Comment: Jeremy:  I'm thinking more about the latency side of things.  1300kbps TCP connection is great, but if there's 600ms of latency that severely disrupts the throughput.  So one socket may cap out at 200kbps, but if I can send 5 packets at once I should see ~1000kbps